# RecyclerView animation onRemove with fixed item

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I wonder how to enforce RecyclerView to do proper/nice animation while deleting item before one with fixed position and specific layout.

I have tried to build on this [tutorial](http://frogermcs.github.io/recyclerview-animations-androiddevsummit-write-up/), which works fine until my specific demands.

Just simple changes to tutorial code:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position == 3){
        return IREGULAR;
    }
    return REGULAR;
}

@Override
public ColorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if(viewType == REGULAR) {
         view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    }else{
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_iregular, parent, false);
    }

    // rest of tutorial code down here
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ColorViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int color;
    if(getItemViewType(position) == REGULAR) {
        color = colors.get(position);
    }else{
        color = 0xFF000000;
    }
    // rest of tutorial code down here
}
```

So third item will be little bit higher and always black.

[image]

As you can see on picture above, animation works fine until item below third position (iregular one) is deleted, but while it is above then big black space appear where items are re-binded.
**How can I accomplish to have better animation experience?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you remove a row, you must call below methods:

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
```

Comment: This is probably the correct answer while it really works well in demo mentioned above. But in my real project, It does not work properly. Maybe it is due to more complex layout, resp. time spend in onCreate and onBind methods.
While in demo it is nearly 0ms, in my real project it is between 5-33ms.